# How to list environment variables of ALL the processes in a systematic and hierarchical manner

Tags: linux, docker, process, environment-variables

I would like to check on how environment variables are populated and inherited by the Linux processes. It might be particularly useful on those processes not having explicit shell as a parent (Docker container with exec launch type etc)

It would be perfect to get that list in an organized and expressive form like for example `pstree` draws the list of processes with optional extra information.

Unfortunately I have not found a way to have `pstree` list the env vars for all the processes in the tree. There is an `-a` option but looks like it may help only if env vars are passed in a form of command line arguments (which is not always the case)

Of course it is possible to got individual process variables  by e.g. obtaining PIDs with the `pstree -p` and then extracting the envs data with `cat /proc/<PID>/environ` however it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: This is, I think too broad. Each process populates it's environment variables by itself. Each process can `putenv`. So: How environment variables are populated? - by using `putenv` vall. And how is the environment inherited - by the `environ` argument to the `execvpe` call. Drawing "tree of inheritance" of environment variables makes no sense - unless you implement a kernel that stores history of a environment variables, there is no such information available.

Comment: The new process may not inherit the environment, the `environ` argument to `execvpe` may be set explicitly by the caller. There is not really a "inheritance" relation between environment variables in different processes, rather each process has it's own environment (ie. a global `environ` pointer).

Comment: So as I see the `environ` argument is essentially similar to `argc` and `argv` passed to the newly starting process's `main()` function.

Comment: Hm.. And similar to tzname, timezone, daylight, and all the other global variables?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in a portable fashion. Heck, I don't even know of a way to do it non-portably. Env vars are stored in the address space of the process. On Linux the */proc/$pid/environ* only shows the vars as they existed when the process started. It does not show any subsequence modifications to the env vars the process may have made with `putenv()` or `setenv()` or whatever mechanism the language the process was written in uses. Put this in a file named *env_test*:

```
#!/bin/sh
export WTF=hello
export PATH=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
./env_test2 &
/usr/bin/sleep 999
```

Put this in a file named *env_test2*:

```
#!/bin/sh
export WTF=goodbye
export PATH=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
/usr/bin/sleep 999
```

Now type `./env_test &` then `ps waux | grep env_test` to get the pids of the two scripts. Examine the respective */proc/$pid/environ* psuedo-files and notice that the changes made by *env_test* are inherited by *env_test2* and are reflected in its magic */proc/$pid/environ* file but the `export`s done by each script are not reflected in that content.